# ExtJs 4 call functions from another controller synchronously

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller, view

when i tried to execute this code in my controller:

```
epgES.getApplication().getController('epgES.controller.EPGController').newEditorRequest();
epgES.getApplication().getController('epgES.controller.EPGController').updateViewRangeControl(Ext.Date.parseDate(eventStart, "c"));
```

first line have to initialise my controller, create a view and load all store, while second have just to call one of controller's functions and change the date range after controller is completely loaded.
But I noticed that the second line executes while the first haven't already finished and all the logic that I want to implement becomes broken.
How to deal with this problem and execute these two methods "synchronously" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour and the asynchronous nature of how browsers work.

The reason for this is because your browser does not wait after a server response before executing the next line of code. You can witness this when loading a webpage: you can start reading the text before the images are even shown sometimes.

The code that executes in `updateViewRangeControl` (and expects fully loaded stores I assume) has to be ran in the `load` listener of your store, that is loaded in `newEditorRequest`.

Check [this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load) out.

Comment: @antosiy Please mark as answer if it suited your needs.